# How to get response time of a url/website in android service?

Tags: java, android, http, service

I was developing an app to check if a website is responding or not. Also i wanted to know the response time of a particular url.

I used webviewclient for getting the response code.

But I want to implement it in service and webviewclient can't be used in services. I want this to be done only in services and not in activity . Please help.

Any java codes using http to know the response code, response time of url would be helpfull. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the project "httpmon" on google code,

> http://code.google.com/p/httpmon/

it's a little rough, but is a complete version of what you are looking for. it's also on the play store,

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.httpmon&hl=en

DISCLOSURE: this is my app, but it's free and open source.

Comment: thanx a lot for info. Wher can i find the code for this app. Can u pls tel

Comment: the code is at the first link above. if you found this answer helpful,  click on check mark of the left next to it to mark it as such.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I'm now trying to use your Httpmon app. I set up a condition. But I wonder if the alert is triggered when this condition occurs or when it stops occurring. For example, my server returns a 302 on successful request, so I set up a condition on response code to 302 expecting an alert to be sent if the actual returned response code is not 302. Is that the way to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) , an Apache Commons class that is shipped along with the Android library. This class can be used to send asynchronous requests and receive them. You can use this along with services or async tasks.